# Sharing Javascript files with other projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript file in another project which is used for validation. I want this file available for my website main project file. How do I go about doing this?

I am using asp.net MVC4.

thanks...

The project files are in a solution folder in visual studio and want to reference to the file in another project.

Comment: You can copy it over.

Comment: Can you create the Virtual Directory of Script folder of another project, inside the website in IIS ?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use NuGet.

You can add your own custom repository: [Hosting Your Own NuGet Feeds](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep one physical copy of the file, you can keep it in one place, and add it as a "linked" file in your other projects:

[image]